# SSO infrastructure for Linux+Win clients

Tags: linux, single-sign-on

I currently have an office network revolving essentially around three services, all hosted under Linux:

- Shared storage area served via Samba.
- Mail Web/IMAP handled by Zimbra.
- Project management/bugtracking handled by RedMine.
- Other, smaller, services are available (e.g.: git repo).

All these are actually self hosted into a set of managed VMs.

Clients may be local, over the internet (for web services) or remoted via VPN.

Clients are either windows (the majority) or linux.

Currently all services have independent user/pass management and this, coupled with need to periodically change passwords is rapidly leading to a nightmare as user base enlarges (currently I have ~100 users).

Is there some way to manage a Single Sign-on for these (few, bit different) services?

Optimal would be to have a single Authentication Server where each user can manage a dingle password for all services and Administrator can assign (rather specific, at least as Samba and Git are concerned) privileges to users.

Does such system exist?

I am aware some very big services (e.g.: google) can provide authentication for other (mainly web) services, but I'm  unsure if this can be scaled down to a single (relatively) Small Office.

Comment: You're describing a need for an LDAP system. Microsot makes a good canned one, called Active Directory. For Linux solutions to this, take a look at the latest versions of FreeIPA, which is slightly less canned yet easier to administrate in many scenarios. There's also always OpenLDAP, which is an excellent LDAP system for an experienced sysadmin to set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows domain, can elaborate some SSO autentication using the active directory validation.

If you dont have a windows domain, can use the ldap preinstalled on zimbra or (my prefer option), implement your own LDAP authentication server to manage all that scenarie.

Answer (score 0):

Univention Corporate Server (UCS) is a Debian-based server OS for corporate environments, which integrates a central identity management (IDM) based on OpenLDAP. It can be managed via a web interface and offers various apps like Zimbra, mail server, Samba, Redmine via the Univention App Center. These apps are already integrated into the UCS domain and can therefore use the identity management.

This video gives a quick overview of UCS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4JvLyaZfTA

If you want to try UCS, feel free to download the free and unlimited Core Edition: https://www.univention.com/downloads/ucs-download/

Full disclosure: I work at the Professional Services department @ Univention in Bremen, feel free to ask further questions!